# Best way to get gems from clearing obstacles?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Sometimes I find gems when clearing obstacles and sometimes I don't.  Is this truly random?  Has anyone seen a pattern?  For instance, I seem to never find gems in the second, third, or fourth obstacle, but if I wait a few hours and spread them out, my gem-finding rate goes up.

Am I imagining this or is there some pattern we can all make use of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's random, but different obstacles may offer a better shot at more gems. Specifically, I think there's a "gem chest" obstacle that may show up occasionally...?

The Sims Social (on Facebook) had a very similar mechanic, including the reward chests. Some players never destroyed their obstacles on purpose to keep them around because they looked cool!

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly not random: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Obstacles

But I could not get the same pattern. Here what I got (so far): 0,3,0,4,2,1,1

Comment: Please quote the relevant portion of the linked page.  This ensures that if the page ever goes down, we still have the information here.